# How to call SQLite Cursor objects between functions?

Tags: python, sqlite

Im getting familiar with Python these days and was writing a simple code to access a SQLite Database and display data throgh a SELECT query. I have been focusing the procedural programming aspect so Database connection and data retrieval was written in to 2 functions as follows.

```
def AccessDB():
    global BCDB,curVehicle,VehicleTB
    BCDB = sqlite3.connect('D:\CabDB.sqlite')
    curVehicle = BCDB.cursor() 
    VehicleTB = BCDB.cursor()

def getData(): 
    curVehicle.execute('SELECT * FROM Vehicle')                                                                             
    Result=curVehicle.fetchall()
    print(Result[0])
    List1.insert(0,Result[0][0])
```

and then the main program:

```
AccessDB()
getData()
```

When executed, I get following error:

```
line 57, in getData
curVehicle.execute('SELECT * FROM Vehicle')  
NameError: name 'curVehicle' is not defined
```

Line 57 refers to .execute statement.
I suspect this means the global variable is not accepted in calling scope could be the issue.
Any ideas whats wrong with this code?

Comment: are AccessDB and getData defined within the same module as the main program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply defining variables outside of the function worked for me:

```
BCDB,curVehicle,VehicleTB = (0,0,0)
def AccessDB():
    BCDB = sqlite3.connect('D:\CabDB.sqlite')
    curVehicle = BCDB.cursor() 
    VehicleTB = BCDB.cursor()

def getData(): 
    curVehicle.execute('SELECT * FROM Vehicle')                                                                             
    Result=curVehicle.fetchall()
    print(Result[0])
    List1.insert(0,Result[0][0])
```

You do need to define a variable outside of a function so then you could modify it inside the function.